# Google Dialogflow - Asking a customer for a unique number

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I am trying to ask a customer for a unique number. I have tested this using the test console and it's coming up with multiple variations without giving a value.

The numbers are a mix of 4/6/8 digits. I want a customer to be able to say 'my plan number is 12345678' and for me to be able to get that value and work with it.

What parameters/system entities should I be using to get a result? Often times it will miss a digit/put in a hyphen etc.

P.S. this is using voice only, not text.

Answer (score 0):

There's a feature called [Auto speech adaptation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/speech-adaptation) that will help you in this specific case. After enabling it, check the point 5 in the [Example speech recognition improvements](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/speech-adaptation#example_speech_recognition_improvements). It explains how you can use auto speech adaptation with Regexp entities to capture digit sequences and it gives you a regular expression you can use. It also recommends using **@sys.number-sequence** entity.

The [enhanced speech models](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/data-logging) can also help with the number identification accuracy, but bear in mind that it is still a beta feature.

For reference you can also check the article [Improving speech recognition for contact centers](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/ai-machine-learning/improving-speech-recognition-for-contact-centers) in the Google Cloud Blog.